# keep argument in url with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, edit, member

I am probably just not understanding how this really works, but i want to keep the argument in the URL with codeigniter. 
I have a form that has the url ../dashboard/edit_member/33 where dashboard is my controller and edit_member is my method and 33 is the ID of the member i am editing.
So when i hit submit and go through my form validation etc.. i use

```
public function edit_member($id = NULL) {

    $this->load->library("form_validation");

    $data['member'] = $this->User->get_user($id);

    if($this->input->post('submit')) { 
        if($this->update_profile() == True) { 
            $data['message'] = 'Profile updated';
        } else {
            $data['message'] = 'There was a problem updating your record';
        }
    } 

    $this->load->view("edit_member", $data);        
}
```

But my issue is when its submitted, it comes back to ../dashboard/edit_member with no id attached to it anymore...

Am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask,what is the action url of the form,have you a form_open()? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: hi - I used <?php echo form_open('dashboard/edit_member'); ?>

Comment: Why not <?php echo form_open('dashboard/edit_member/'.$id(user id)); ?>

Comment: remove NULL from here $id = NULL and try

Comment: Totally right dimis283. changed it to <?php echo form_open("dashboard/edit_member/{$member->id}"); ?> ... Should have thought of that. I'm new to CI so still working through it :) thanks!